# Assembly prints the second message twice

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I was learning subroutines in nasm assembly for linux (running on a kali machine). I made the code below and the out put prints "Hello World 2\n" twice, and I can't figure out why. Can someone explain?

```
section .data
msg db "Hello World", 0Ah     ; message 1
msg2 db "Hello World 2", 0Ah  ; message 2

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, msg          ; load message to registar
    call strlen           ; get length of string through subroutine
    mov edx, eax          ; sets string length
    mov eax, 4            ; kernel code for write
    mov ebx, 1            ; use std
    mov ecx, msg          ; buffer is msg
    int 80h                

    mov eax, msg2         ; does the same thing with msg2
    call strlen
    mov edx, eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg2
    int 80h               ; this gets run twice for some reason?

    mov eax, 1            ; exit with code 0
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

strlen:
    push ebx          ; use stack to preserve registar ebx
    mov ebx, eax      ; moves eax into the preserved registar

nextchar:
    cmp byte [eax], 0 ; compares the the byte to 0, if it is true,
    jz finished       ; jumps down or else increments one and
    inc eax           ; starts this part again
    jmp nextchar

finished:
    sub eax, ebx      ; subtracts the two values so that you get the
    pop ebx           ; string length, then restores ebx, and returns
    ret               ; to where it was called
```

Comment: `strlen` probably expects a zero-terminated string.

Comment: `cmp byte [eax], 0`.  I think Your messages should end with 0.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thank you, I replace it with `cmp byte [eax], 0Ah` and now it runs once. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to figure out that either `cmp byte [eax], 0` needed to be changed to `cmp byte [eax], 0Ah`, which didn't preserve the newline, or I could add `,0` to the end of each message, which worked to.

Thanks for the help!